# Compelling example of difference between intended consequences and foreseen but unintended consequences?

Tags: ethics, practical-ethics

I am trying to get inside the head of individuals who believe that there is a difference between acting in such a way that someone's death foreseeably results from your actions, but that this was not your intention, and in acting  in this way when the death was your intention.

In particular, I can see the instrumental value of treating the latter case as a worse offense, but I cannot see any argument as to why it would be fundamentally worse.

Does anybody have any compelling examples which might help drive this point home for me? EG in the case of act vs omission, I can consider murdering someone vs not donating to charity, and whilst I ultimately think about these things still in consequentialist terms, the example gives me insight into other ways of thinking about the matter. I have no such example for cases like this so far.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Consider serial killer who killed terrorist and saved lives. He will be worse than those who intented to save lives through killing terrorist, because he is potentially dangerous. And yes, this is consequential mechanism in humans. Yet, intuitive an emotional, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

This distinction is called the [Doctrine of Double Effect](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/double-effect), and it has a very influential originator, Aquinas himself, who broke with St. Augustine on the permissibility of killing in self-defense:

> “*Nothing hinders one act from having two effects, only one of which is intended, while the other is beside the intention. …Accordingly, the act of self-defense may have two effects: one, the saving of one's life; the other, the slaying of the aggressor.*”

The doctrine is controversial, many see it as a distinction without a substantive difference. Be it as it may, empirical research in moral psychology shows that people are psychologically predisposed to draw the distinction, for good reason or not. In particular, it is one of the explanations for the different responses to the two versions of the so-called trolley dilemma, see [Waldmann et al. review](https://www.psych.uni-goettingen.de/de/cognition/publikationen-dateien-wiegmann/2012_WaldmannNagelWiegmann_Moraljudgment_.pdf).

In the *bystander* version of the dilemma, the driver of a trolley heading toward five people on the track faints. A passenger can redirect the trolley towards a side track with one person, who will be killed. Eighty five percent of the subjects in the Hauser's study find this morally acceptable. In the *footbridge* version of the dilemma a runaway trolley is also heading towards five people. An onlooker standing on a bridge above the tracks realizes that he can stop the trolley with a heavy weight. The only available heavy weight is a large man standing next to him. Only twelve percent find pushing that man off the bridge acceptable.

Presumably, in the bystander situation killing the unlucky guy is unintended but foreseeable, hence ok, while in the footbridge situation it is intended, and not ok. However, attributing the differing reactions to double effect is controversial. An alternative explanation, favored by Greene, Haidt and others, is that people react much stronger emotionally to "personal" than to "impersonal" killing, because we evolved in an environment dominated by the former. Double effect is just a clever rationalization of emotions.

Given the notorious unreliability of self-discerning of "intentions", which in Aquinas's time was not yet recognized, how the distinction is to be made in general is also not entirely clear. One way is in terms of degrees of causal proximity, a rational version of personal/impersonal, the more  actions allow for potential causal interventions, the "saving grace", the "last minute miracle", the more their foreseeable adverse consequences are to be morally discounted. However, subjects' reactions in moral dilemmas seem to correlate much better with emotional responses than with assessments of causal proximity.

Comment: I predict that even wording of "Fat Man" problem can affect the percentage of people: "Is it right to save 5 people, even if the man on the bridge will need to be sacrificed to save those people" vs "Is it right to push that man from the pridge in order to save 5 people".

Answer (score 2):

INTENDED CONSEQUENCES

I decide to kill X. I administer a lethal dose of poison to X in order to kill her. The consequence is that X dies. X's death is an intended consequence of my administering the lethal dose.

FORESEEN BUT UNINTENDED CONSEQUENCES

Y is in great pain and is in a condition of terminal illness. On the best calculations, Y has two days to live. I may administer a pain killer which I foresee will as a side effect cause Y's death in two hours. But Y's death is not something I intend to bring about. Y's death is unintended in the sense that I do not aim to cause Y's death; I merely foresee it as the unintended (unaimed for) consequence of what I do intend to do, and do intentionally, namely remove Y's pain.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 scenario's are the same.  In scenario 2 X is given human form. If the pain reliever causes death and is known before you administer it for pain you are not relieving pain you are killing the host of the pain knowing it will end in a definit outcome of death &in 2hours is a foreseen consequence. Same as SCENARIO 1. If it cannot be done without death as "forseen" end result it is not unintentional. Only if administer was unaware in every way possible that death would be the end result is it  unintended consequences.

Comment: Your "Intentions might have been to end the pain " but the consequences are still intended due to KNOWING BEFORE HAND THAT DEATH WAS THE RESULT NOT THE END OF PAIN THE RESULT.

Comment: If you have references to others who take a similar view this would give the reader a place to go for more information and support the answer.  Welcome!